# how to use convert to center an 512x512 jpg onto a blank 1024x500 image?

Tags: imagemagick-convert

I have a 512x512 jpeg file, but I need a 1024x500 image jpegfile.  I thought I could do something use convert like this:

```
convert my512x512.jpg -page "1024x500" my1024x500.jpg
```

But when I open my1024x500.jpg it is still 512x512.  I have also tried ...

```
convert my512x512.jpg -resize "1024x500!" my1024x500.jpg
```

... but that distorts the image.  How can I center my 512x512 in a 1024x500 jpeg file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! I figured it out.

```
convert my512x512.jpg -background none -gravity center -extent '1024x500!' my1024x500.jpg
```